# How to remove <br> within a <textarea></textarea> only

Tags: php

I have some articles stored in a text field in my database. There are times when the article includes `<textarea>content.....</textarea>`
The problem is that when the content is displayed on a page using php, it includes the actual `<br><br><br>`. The `<br>` is placed there by the text editor (CKEditor)
So it looks like the following

> `<textarea>` <-- this actually becomes a textarea
>
> This content is shown inside the text area`<br>`
> but the problem is that the `<br>`
> is also shown.
> `</textarea>`

How can I strip `<br>` from the `<textarea>` tags only. I imagine some preg replace would be useful.

Comment: Well, I hate to be a syntax Nazi without answering your question, but you should use `<br />` instead of `<br>`.

Comment: @Cory: Not if your doctype is HTML4. Then a syntax Nazi would screech that <br /> is INVALID HTML.

Comment: My mistake, it does actually place the <br />. This, as I mentioned is done automatically by CKEditor. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use an HTML parser to do it:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('textarea') as $textarea) {
  foreach ($textarea->childNodes as $child) {
    if ($child->nodeName == 'br') {
      $textarea->removeChild($child);
    }
  }
}
$content = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Basically regexes are a poor tool for processing HTML because HTML isn't "regular" in the sense of "regular expression". This means it doesn't handle things like nested elements without using an unreliable hack.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works great for getting rid of the <br> but it seems to place the content outside of `<textarea></textarea>`
Is there any way to keep the content inside the textarea? Thanks again.

Comment: Actually the `<br />` are not removed, the content is just placed outside of the textarea instead.

Comment: What do you mean they're getting placed outside the textarae?

Comment: despite reading hundreds of **"USE A HTML PARSER!!"** answers on Stack Overflow, this is actually the first one I've seen that actually gives some sample code. +1

Comment: @ cletus, When I use your code, the result is the following
`<textarea></textarea>`
The content is then removed from the textarea and placed under it. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

```
$x='<br><textarea>abcd<br>efgh</textarea><br><br>';

echo preg_replace('/<textarea>.*?<\/textarea>/e','str_replace("<br>","","\\0")',$x);

//<br><textarea>abcdefgh</textarea><br><br>
```

If you using `<br />`, please update it appropriately.

Comment: This works great for `<textarea>`. How can I tweak it for instances where the textarea contains attributes.
Example:
`<textarea rows="10" name="test">Content with `<br>`</textarea>`
Thanks.

Comment: Like this: echo preg_replace('/<textarea[^>]*?>.*?<\/textarea>/e','str_replace("<br>","","\\0")',$x);

Comment: Thanks infamouse for follow up, I missed to read his comment, and `?` may not needed in `<textarea[^>]*>`

Answer (score 0):

here's one way

```
$str= <<<A
    <textarea> <-- this actually becomes a textarea

    This content is shown inside the text area<br> but the problem is that the <br> is also shown. </textarea>
A;
$s = explode("</textarea>",$str);
for($i=0;$i<count($s)-1;$i++){
    if(strpos($s[$i],"<textarea>")!==FALSE){
        $s[$i] = preg_replace("/<br>/","",$s[$i]);
    }
}
print implode("</textarea>",$s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at what the database is storing - maybe it's HTMLencoding it before writing to the database and so what you're seeing is actually :

```
&lt;br /&gt;
```

This can happen when you use fields generated by CKEditor and TinyMCE as it escapes fields before $_POSTing

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the answer it is so strange.. but it fixed the problem.

as i notice.. if we write line 1
line2
line3

it actually write a the content with multi line and without 
 or  or whatever

so i do the following function

---

```
function clear_string($string) { 
$string = str_replace(array('\r\n', '\r', '\n'), '
', $string); 
return $string; 
}
```

---

and i use it whenever i want to save the content of textarea and save it on variable, also i can know easily echo the value of the variable for the textarea ... for example

```
<textarea><?php echo $notes;?> </textarea>
```

thank you so much for your help

and i hope it helps people who face same problem

Comment: the answer is simple. you should not store these <br>'s at all, but add it dynamically before HTML output

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML...

```
<textarea id="text">Some text here.<br>Some other text.</textarea>
```

...perform this Javascript...

```
document.getElementById('text').value = document.getElementById('text').value.replace(/<br>/g,'\r');
```