# <br /> shown in textarea on editing

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is in the textarea i get `<br/>` on editing it. On showing the o/p as a alert, the right solution is obtained. but if alert is removed then again `<br />` is seen in the textarea. It changes on every refresh alternatively. This is my piece of code:

```
  $('#' + type).is("input");  {     
      element = element.replace(/<br *\/?>/gi,'\r');        
      $('#' + type).val(element);    
  }
```

As per me the code inside the curly braces works good which I have picked from the same site. but as i have placed this code in the js file there should be something else which overwrites this. Similar questions where asked in this site but none of the solutions worked for me. Am trying this code in js file. Please let me know a solution for this.
On opening the frame in new tab in mozilla no `<br/>` is seen. but when the same frame is opened in chrome & IE again `<br/>` is shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove <br> within a <textarea></textarea> only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010851/how-to-remove-br-within-a-textarea-textarea-only)

Comment: What do you mean by `$('#' + type).is("input");  {`? Are you intending to write an `if` statement?

Comment: yes its a if statement...if textarea kind of